# fonttools convert ttf to woff2

Tags: fonts, ttx-fonttools

Currenly, I'm using fonttools(https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools) to convert font file `ttf` to `woff2` by `ttx` command with 2 steps

- convert `ttf` to `ttx`
- then convert `ttx` to `woff2`

But it's too slow and `ttx` file to big, is there any way to convert `ttf` to `woff2` directly by using fonttools to improve performance?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With fonttools installed in your Python (virtualenv, pipenv, etc):

```
$ python
>>> from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont
>>> f = TTFont('path/to/your/file.otf')
>>> f.flavor='woff2'
>>> f.save('path/to/your/file.woff2')
```

NOTE: you might need to install other `fontTools` dependencies ('brotli', others) to allow saving with `flavor=woff2` to work correctly.

Comment: Or as a shell oneliner:
python -c "from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont; f = TTFont('path/to/your/file.otf');f.flavor='woff2';f.save('path/to/your/file.woff2')"

Answer (score 5):

```
pip install --user --upgrade fonttools[woff]
python3
>>> from fontTools.ttLib.woff2 import compress
>>> compress('filename.otf','filename.woff2')
```

- This will [only] accept .otf and .ttf
- It produces smaller files than other techniques (ie: woff2-tools)

https://fonttools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ttLib/woff2.html?highlight=ttLib.woff2%3A#fontTools.ttLib.woff2.compress

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly want I needed in my case, converting otf to woff2

Answer (score 2):

There's [Google's woff2 CLI](https://github.com/google/woff2), so you can do this in command line instead of manually writing some scripts.

Answer (score 1):

If you install fonttools with the right dependencies, you can also this from the command-line:

```
./fonttools ttLib Roboto-Regular.ttf --flavor woff2 Roboto-Regular.woff2
```

Comment: in my case I had just installed fonttools, and in order to run the above, I had to install brotli.
`pip install brotli`